# Objective-C Displaying Numbers as Words Using Math

Tags: objective-c, c, math

I have an exercise in my Objective-C book in which I must design a program using only the knowledge the book has given me so far to do so. It tells me to use math to do this not any methods from Objective-C.

What I must do is get any integer from the user and then convert each number to a word.

For example if the user enters: 956
The output must then be:

```
nine
five
six
```

I am not the best math student and definitely need help here. I can of course use loops of any kind as well as if statements and basic math operators as well as arrays but no built in methods.

I assume that I need to get each digit separated into its own integer variable and then use switch of if statements to then create the strings and display them but cannot successfully do this.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: This is a fairly common interview question. It is not limited to any particular language. I suggest you start simple as a learning exercise and then look at some of the more complex solutions out there.

Comment: *...need help here...* Where, exactly, do you need help? If you're doing an exercise from a book, then presumably you want to solve the problem yourself. When you say you *cannot successfully do this*, what **this** are you talking about? Can you display a string? Can you write a `switch` statement? Considering that all the info you need is in your book, have you considered re-reading the relevant sections?

Comment: Yes and yes but I cannot split each number up into its own int variable which is what I was asking. @Caleb

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I quickly came up with. See the comments in the code below for an explanation.

```
    //Create an array of number strings. They must be in order starting from 0 so the indexes line up
    NSArray *numbers = @[@"zero", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five", @"six", @"seven", @"eight", @"nine"];

    //Create whatever string you're processing
    NSString *numString = @"956";

    //Loop through the substrings of the number string
    while (numString.length > 0) {

        //Get the first character in the string
        int currentNum = [[numString substringToIndex:1] intValue];

        //Print the number. The number string should be at the index of this value in the array
        NSLog(@"%@", numbers[currentNum]);

        //Remove everything before the first character
        numString = [numString substringFromIndex:1];
    }
```

Output:

```
nine
five
six
```

Comment: I am suppose to use math to solve this not methods or strings to split these up. Thanks for that answer though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "supposed to use math"... And you aren't splitting the string up necessarily, you're iterating through the characters in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using C (one of your tags):

This one makes use of a `char *[]` (array of C strings) and ascii values of each char...

```
char *number[]={"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

int main(void)
{
    char dig[20];
    int len, i;

    printf("enter integer: ");   //instruction to user
    scanf("%s", dig);   //read from user
    len = strlen(dig);  
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(dig[i]))//test to verify good user input (accept only digits)
        {
            printf("%s\n", number[dig[i]-48]); // 48-57 is range of ASCII values for 0-9
        }
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

***Example session:***
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but not what I am looking for. I have to use primarily math as what the book has gone over so far does not cover things like ASCII values.

Comment: That's okay, but ***[ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)*** are intrinsic to just about any programming you will do.